# JSON based rules evaluator for Java

Tags: java, rules, rule-engine

I want to develop a JSON rule schema and a rules evaluator where I can define and/or/nor conditions on individual conditions for attribute comparison. For example - the below rule will evaluate to true if customerType is PRIMARY and locale is en-US. I am planning to write my custom rules evaluator in Java which takes rules JSON as input along with request parameters and evaluates to true or false based on its a match or not. I am keeping my schema generic and open for extensions. Like if you want to support "OR" condition in future, or if you want to support operators like ">=" in future you could do so by extending your rules evaluator. Are there any better ways to do it? Is my schema flexible enough?

```
"rule": {
            "type": "CompositeRule",
            "allOf": [ #In future, we can also support "anyOf" if required
              {
                "type": "SimpleRule",
                "attribute": "customerType",
                "operator": "==", #In future, we can also support other operators like ">=" or "<=" etc.
                "value": "PRIMARY" #Value can be a number, string or boolean
              },
              {
                "type": "SimpleRule",
                "attribute": "locale",
                "operator": "==",
                "value": "en-US"
              }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to write this yourself, rather than using a premade validation library/package?

Comment: I did not come across with any such library therefore decided to write it myself.

Comment: In under a minute of web searching, I found http://java-source.net/open-source/validation - there's no doubt many more validators to be found with some more searching, based on now knowing the terms these libraries use.

Comment: I am not sure if we can use a validation library here. My requirement is - I would have 100s of rules defined. When I get a request, I evaluate all rules against parameters  in request and find a matching rule.